# Htaccess redirectmatch only works for http urls

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My site is a wordpress on Https. using an Apache server. It is in public_html the folder and there is no private_html folder.
I am trying to setup a redirect with the htaccess.

My /out/ folder is followed by a url of a partner. I want the users to be forwarded to that url.

In my htaccess I have:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /out/(.*) $1
```

The issue is that the code somehow keeps adding my own domain in front of the external url

```
https://example.com/out/https://externaldomain.com
```

should go

```
to https:// externaldomain.com
```

but it goes to:

```
https://example.com/https://externaldomain.com
```

Hoaever, if I change my own url to http instead of https, it does work

```
http://example.com/out/https://externaldomain.com
```

goes to

```
https:// externaldomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/out/(https?://.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Or using just `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^out/(https?:)/(.+)$ $1//$2 [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure you test from a new browser or completely clear browser cache.

Comment: why not just `RewriteRule ^/out/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]`?

Comment: That won't work because RewriteRule strips all multiple slashes into a single slash

Comment: Interesting, I never noticed it did, and there's no flag to avoid it. I guess you could go with `RewriteRule ^out/(http[s]*:)/(.+)$ $1//$2 [L,NE,R=301]` to "simplify" it, but mostly to avoid invalid redirect (if what follows "out" is not a URL)

Comment: Yes same can be done using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/out/(https?://.+)$ [NC]` also

Comment: Thanks a lot,  just using the rewriterule worked (the other one did not for some reason),  for urls that are just http, i can just set a second rewriterule with http? instead of https?.  (i was afraid i had to do this with php, really happy this works!!)

Comment: Glad it worked. Rule should work for `https` also as I have regex as `https?` which makes `s` optional after `http`